# How did you learn UML?

Tags: uml

I'm going to start learning and using UML.

I need to know what considerations do you suggest for me?  What is the best way to learn effectively it do you think?

Thank you

Comment: I, for one, found this question (above), and these answers (below) particularly constructive. Refreshingly so. Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 6):

In a class named *SE101- Software Engineering 1A* at [CPIT](http://www.cpit.ac.nz/) in New Zealand.

In my opinion, you'll find that sequence and use case diagrams will be essential for getting ideas across to non-programmers, and class diagrams (and object diagrams, to a lesser extent), for communicating ideas to other code-monkeys.

Plus, many programming books that you may read in the future, [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29), for example, will use UML diagrams (class and object, mostly) to show the structure of the patterns. Knowing UML will make understanding these books a lot easier. Documentation, too, to a lesser extent.

Answer (score 5):

I never did, and I never will. Modelling is not about mastering a type of discipline, good models don't need UML to be understood.

Comment: UML is about unifying a modeling method so that everybody can understand what you are meaning by your model. Yes you can have a good model without UML but will everybody understand it?

Comment: My argument is that if everybody can't understand it, it's not a good model (with or without knowledge of UML). That's not to say that a model can't be complex. It takes time and effort to understand the model, that however, won't change just becuase you try to unify how your chose to represent your model with something like UML.

Comment: +1 for adding some balance to the answers. While UML has its uses, it is not the be-all-and-end-all that many others would suggest. (The way people talk about UML now reminds me of how people used to talk about flow diagrams!).

Comment: The question was specifically about learning UML - besides it is a standard, and it is something everyone already knows/can learn so communication is much easier using UML.

Comment: @Roopesh - Yes, and my argument is that you shouldn't blindly apply a process without understanding why. To be fair, my understanding of UML is limited but I do know a thing or two about project management and communication. UML doesn't solve any of those, soft problems.

Comment: UML is not meant to solve soft problems - it was never meant to - it was meant to be a uniform way to communicate a modeled behavior for a proposed system. Just imagine you have to send your team's design to a client half-way around the world, each of you having own notations of how the model should be interpretted - for eg, what an arrow means.. - its bound to cause mayhem. UML is there to solve THAT. Nothing else.

Comment: What I find is that there are better ways to address issues with communication then to apply UML. Any problem involving people is a stereotypical soft problem, any communication with other people is bound to have misunderstandings. If I wish to relay information, I'd think long and hard why I'd use UML in an attempt to communicate. The receiving end might be able to decipher a sequence diagram with aid but I still question the sanity of something like UML because it isn't ubiquitous to every human. I just don't believe there's much merit to tools like UML in today's environment.

Comment: -1 for this non-answer. He didn't ask if learning UML is a good idea, he asked how to go about learning it.

Comment: @NateC-K I think the best way to learn UML is to approach UML carefully, think, what do you want to communicate, and not, how do you wan't to communicate. Learning how to use a tool, is more important, than picking a specific tool. If this doesn't appeal to you, you are free to down vote my answer.

Comment: The *only* good thing about UML is that it has become a lingua franca. Otherwise, it is an egregious sapir-whorf trap.

Comment: As a programmer lots of thing goes and come in our mind while solving a problem, UML helps to keep us on track.

Answer (score 4):

First, get a book/tutorial and try to understand the basics (definitions, models drawing, ...)
then, learn by example and practice, imagine or use a real problem and try to model it.

Answer (score 3):

I started by reading an introductory book - Martin Fowler UML Distilled was quite good. Than I decided I really want to know how to use it, so I read a book about UML2 and UP (Unified Process) by Jim Arlow and Ila Neustadt. Afterward I had opportunity to take software engineering basics lecture at university which made me create simple specification with few diagrams. Afterward I took UML lecture, where I had again to create some UML diagrams. Now I am in the phase when UML is clear and I feel I need more knowledge about OO modeling, so I read a book on object oriented data modeling and object oriented programming and there are Use Cases by Alistair Cockbourne and some analytical patterns ahead for me. In between I read much of the model driven stuff and listened to SE Radio about all UML stuff - http://www.se-radio.net/tags/uml .

Answer (score 3):

[UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020165783X) by Martin Fowler together with [Applying UML And Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062) by Craig Larman, makes you understand the concept of UML and how to use it - as well the whole process with UP and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.smartdraw.com/resources/tutorials/uml-diagrams/#/resources/tutorials/Getting-Started

This link was very helpful for me to learn modeling with UML.
For open source solutions check out Dia, and dia2code.

Answer (score 1):

I read Martin Fowler's [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687).  That's all you need.  It's thin, dense book that's unmatched on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

- I have several UML books, `UML Distilled` book from Addison Wesley comes to mind,
- then it all gets familiar when you start reading Design Pattern books that illustrates the concepts using UML Diagrams.
- I also use UML when I sketch a design.

Answer (score 0):

You can only focus on 2 diagrams and start modeling almost immediately.
Usecase diagrams require reading but class diagram can be done at the same time as the code. It means that in less than 3 hours you can model.

**Usecase diagram** is simple and will help you to define the scope of your project.

**Class diagram** will define the physical architecture and can therefore be learned at the same time as codding if you use a tool having live code and model synchronization.

Don't spend time on model driven and code generation from a model because nobody really use it today !!

Answer (score 0):

[Inventor](http://www.ivarjacobson.com).
Sequence diagrams look more like business processes and usecases rather unstandardized.